# Apache 2.4.7 error client denied by server configuration: /home/appname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, server, hosting, digital-ocean

So I am using digital ocean to host my ruby on rails application

I used this tutorial on how to deploy it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

After completing it I have tried to access my server through its IP address and it gives me a 403 Access Denied Error and checking the apache error log I find the following message:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/appname, referer: http://IPADDRESS/
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/appname.conf files is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.peerparking.com
    ServerAlias www.peerparking.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/peerparking/peerparking/peerparking/public
    RailsEnv development

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    DocumentRoot /home/peerparking/peerparking/peerparking/public
    RailsEnv development

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/peerparking/peerparking/peerparking/public>
           Require all granted
           Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My ruby on rails app is located at /username/home/appname/appname/appname

Dont ask why I have three successive folders named the same, I messed up pulling from my repository

Comment: I'm having the same problem after upgrade Apache version (from 2.2 to 2.4).